# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, pygame, wxpython

I'm a Newbe in the Python Object Oriented Pogramming So, I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx, pygame, sys, random, os
from pygame.locals import *
from random import choice
from block import O, I, S, Z, L, J, T

class Example(wx.Frame):


def __init__(self, parent, id, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Example, self).__init__(self, parent, id,*args, **kwargs)  
    self.InitUI()
    image_file = "roses.jpg"
    bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))
[more stuffs...]
```

And It is supose to open a Window with some buttons an a Background Image. But when I execute it it gives me an error:

```
File "C:\mytetris\aaa.py", line 472, in main
Example(None)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

So please, help me...

Comment: indentions are incorrect.

Comment: where is `line 472 in main` ?

Comment: Actually... The programs only has 471 lines...

Answer (score 0):

I can only guessing

```
class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, *args, **kwargs):
```

`Example` expects at least 3 arguments `self`, `parent`, `id`. Object name is passed as `self` so you have to create object with 2 arguments - for example:

```
my_example = Example(some_parent, some_id)
```